# Save and retrieve data from firebase database Android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project where I have to do a custom "tour/trip" based on the locations the user chooses on the map.
and every tour has a title, with the locations that he chose.
say for example he made a tour(list) and called it 'Tour 1' and in this 'Tour 1' first he wants to go to the hotel, and then to KFC, and then to the beach.

I'm at the point where I made a list and gave it a title, but can't show the places that I planned to go in the activity, here is a screenshot of the activity [activity example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF9xP.png), and here is a screenshot of my realtime database.

[image: realtime database example]

so I want to show all the places that I planned to go, where it says 'Place 1' in the activity.
here is my code.

```
userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersToursList").child(userID);

userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            tourList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot tourSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Tour tour = tourSnapshot.getValue(Tour.class);
                tourList.add(tour);
            }
            MyToursListAdapter adapter = new MyToursListAdapter(MyToursActivity.this,tourList);
            list_view_tours.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

here is the Adapter class

```
class MyToursListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tour> {

private Activity mContext;
private List<Tour> TourList;

public MyToursListAdapter(Activity mContext, List <Tour>  TourList) {
    super(mContext,R.layout.tours_item_list,TourList);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.TourList = TourList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView tvTourTitle,tvPlace;
    LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
    View listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tours_item_list,null,true);
    tvTourTitle = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_list_tv_TourTitle);
    tvPlace = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_list_tv_place);

    Tour tour = TourList.get(position);

    tvTourTitle.setText(tour.getTourTitle());
    tvPlace.setText(tour.getPlace());

    return listItemView;
}
```

Tour class

```
class Tour {

String place;

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}
```

I hope you understand.

**EDIT**: based on @Simran Sharma request I'll post the whole code that is realted to this issue.

First, **Tour.java**

```
class Tour {

String tourTitle;
String tourID;
String places;

public Tour(){

}
public Tour(String TourTitle,String TourID) {
    tourTitle = TourTitle;
    tourID = TourID;
}

public Tour(String TourTitle,String TourID,String Places) {
    tourTitle = TourTitle;
    tourID = TourID;
    places = Places;
}

public String getTourTitle() {
    return tourTitle;
}

public String getTourID() {
    return tourID;
}

public String getPlaces() {
    return places;
}
```

**MyToursListAdapter.java**, its actually the same as before, but i don't really know if i should use TextView or ListView. so let me know please because i think its an array not a normal string.

here is the code where i **add(save) the place to the list and database**:

```
Query query = myTourUserDatabase.orderByChild("tourTitle").equalTo(ListChosen);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot issue : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            ListID = issue.getKey();
                            Log.d("mytag", "onClick: MapActivity Chosen list ref from spinner " + ListID);

                            TourListChosen_UserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersToursList").child(userID).child(ListID);
                            Map<String, Object> Place = new HashMap<>();
                            Place.put("place",PlaceName);
                            //Tour tour = snapshot.getValue(Tour.class);
                            //places.add(tour);
                            TourListChosen_UserDB.setValue(Place);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

here is the code where i **retreive** the whole list (supposed to be with all the places that i added 'example KFC, Hotel ...' but its not working):

```
userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            tourList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot tourSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Tour tour = tourSnapshot.getValue(Tour.class);
                tourList.add(tour);
            }
            MyToursListAdapter adapter = new MyToursListAdapter(MyToursActivity.this,tourList);
            list_view_tours.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

I think this is all the code what i got about this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so let's start with the Tour.java.

```
class Tour {

    // make these private
    private String tourTitle, tourID;

    // have this public
    ArrayList<Place> places;


    public Tour(){
        // required constructor
    }

    // main constructor
    public Tour(String tourTitle,String tourID) {
        this.tourTitle = tourTitle;
        this.tourID = tourID;
    }


    public String getTourTitle() {
        return tourTitle;
    }

    public String getTourID() {
        return tourID;
    }
}
```

Create another class Place.java

```
class Place {

    private String name;
    
    public Place() {}
    public Place(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I am gonna use the below database reference throughout

```
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userToursList").child(userId);

placesRef = dbRef.child(listId).child("places");
```

So when you want to add a tour do like below:

```
Tour tour = new Tour("Tour1", listId);
dbRef.child(listId).setValue(tour);
```

And when you want to add a new place, use the below code.

```
Place place = new Place("KFC");
placesRef.push().setValue(place);
```

Now in your activity declare the below fields:

```
ArrayList<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();
MyToursListAdapter adapter = new Adapter(MyToursActivity.this, tours);
list_view_tours.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And when you want to retrieve the list of tours:

```
dbRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                
                // check if the snapshot exists or not
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    // the snapshot exists, now retrieve the data
                    Tour tour = snapshot.getValue(Tour.class);

                    if (tour != null) {
                        // update the list with a new tour item
                        tours.add(tour);

                        // tell the adapter that the data has been updated
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
        });
```

And when you want to retrieve the list of places in a particular tour:

```
placesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                
                // check if the snapshot exists or not
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    // the snapshot exists, now retrieve the data
                    Place place = snapshot.getValue(Place.class);
                    
                    if (place != null) {
                        // update the list with a new tour item
                        places.add(place);
 
                        // you can update the places list in the Tour class as well like below
                        tour.places.add(place);
                        // inform adapter that the data has changed so changes can be seen
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
        });
```

Comment: **Thank you SO MUCH** for all the effort, it actually worked pretty well, and so much better than before, But I still have a very small problem, that ill post it as answer from another account, because the question is already so long..

Comment: can you check out this question, its a continue to our conversation..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055110/retrieving-data-from-realtime-database-android-firebase

Comment: I have mentioned some changes on that question of yours. Change them and check if it works.

Comment: Can you please check the question again? Thanks for your effort

Comment: I have commented what is wrong and please change things accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> but can't show the places that I planned to go in the activity

You cannot do that because your "place" field in your "Tour" class cannot be mapped to a dynamic ID. It can be mapped to a property called "place", that can hold a specific value, but you cannot use a fixed property to map those pushed IDs. What you should do instead, is to change your database structure a little bit:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- UserToursList
        |
        --- On3I...Yq72
             |
             --- -MScb...BZUt
                  |
                  --- tourID: "-MScb...BZUt"
                  |
                  --- tourTitle: "Tour 1"
                  |
                  --- places
                       |
                       --- 0: "Jacob Samuel Hotel"
                       |
                       --- 1: "KFC"
                       |
                       --- 2: "Beach"
```

Where the "places" is considered an array. You can simply get that array as a `List<String>` in your Java code.

There is another option, in which you can use a Map<String, Object>, instead of an array, and your schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- UserToursList
        |
        --- On3I...Yq72
             |
             --- -MScb...BZUt
                  |
                  --- tourID: "-MScb...BZUt"
                  |
                  --- tourTitle: "Tour 1"
                  |
                  --- places
                       |
                       --- "Jacob Samuel Hotel": true
                       |
                       --- "KFC": true
                       |
                       --- "Beach": true
```

It's up to you to decide which one fits best.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please show me and example on this code, because this is where i add places to list

`TourListChosen_UserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersToursList").child(userID).child(ListID)
Map<String, Object> Place = new HashMap<>();
Place.put("placeName", PlaceName);
TourListChosen_UserDB.push().setValue(Place);`

Comment: No, it's not correct. The Map should look like this: `Map<String, Object> Place = new HashMap<>();`, add the data inside it like this: `Place.put("Jacob Samuel Hotel", true);` and now write this map the "places" location. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: it didn't work as expected, what should i do with Tour Class and Adapter Class ?
i tried to make array list, but i couldn't make it.. im pretty new to firebase..

Comment: If your `tourID` is a String, you can get it as a String. In the same way, if your `places` is an array, you can get it as a `List<String>`. The same in the case of Map, right?

Comment: Besides that, "it didn't work as expected" doesn't provide much info to understand what's wrong. If you encounter new problems when implementing the above solution, it's best to create a new [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a new question.

Comment: refer to my answer, that will solve the whole issue.

Comment: Plus I don’t think I was clear in this question, sorry for that

Comment: Check the answer below.

Comment: @Simran Sharma I already saw it thanks, but as alex said i should add “places” first to the database, and I don’t know how to be honest, tried many times, I believe there is something wrong with the class and adapter, thats why i asked another question, but thx for the answer :)

Comment: One more thing, I once got an error because py fields were public. Firebase expects the data class fields to be private and the getters to be public. So the `String Places` should be `private String places` with places being lowercase alphatebets.

Comment: @SimranSharma OP wants to have the places added as an array or as a Map, not as a String.

Comment: Ya but I can’t even make “places” :( to be able to add children to it

Comment: I know how you can push that array to the database.

Comment: Let me make an answer about it. I have done it before.

Comment: But for that, @Mr3WD need to put the code for how you upload the data. I'll put an answer to that. I do know how to do it.

Comment: Is there any way i can send you the whole code for adapter, class and where i add places to the list?

Comment: Umm.. I do not know as such. Maybe just update the question by adding some more code.

Comment: @Simran Sharma Edited :)
if you didn't understand the whole problem yet, you can see the other question, i have a screenshot ..

Comment: its included in the edit, how i save the data to database, and retrieve it...

Comment: Give me a minute I am writing the answer.

Comment: I uploaded another answer, I tested it myself with firebase. This should work.

Comment: Does it have any errors? Did it not work? You didn't give any feedback